# Wordpress Ajax & pictures not loading after upgrade to 5.0

Tags: wordpress, javascript, ajax

I've updated from 4.7.29 to 5.0.0
The SQL update went well, but I've issues with JS/Pictures not loading.
This is really blocking as for example, the "Create new contact" is not loading
See screenshots below.
Could you please advise ?
Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> Error at "Create new user page"

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such field"

## 0 /var/www/html/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(3341): civicrm_api3("uf_group", "get", (Array:3))

## 1 /var/www/html/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Address.php(226): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getCreateLinks((Array:3), "shared_address")

## 2 /var/www/html/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Location.php(107): CRM_Contact_Form_Edit_Address::buildQuickForm(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact))

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the missing field "frontend_title" in "civicrm_uf_group" (mentioned in the DB error message"). To fix the issue I did drop the table and recreated it. No more JS error after that.
Special thanks to @Jon G. for his follow-up, however : I could not access the APIv3 from civicrm (it uses JS and wasn't showing up due to the error), I don't know how to use CommandLine. By the way, the APIv3 is now accessible but once "system" is selected for "entity", the choice "rebuildmultilingualschema" for "action" is not proposed; maybe due to the fact that multilingual civicrm is not used on our domain.
Thanks again, best regards

Comment: Seems that this was related to this issue https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11508  / but in civicrm files package wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Upgrade\Incremental\sql I can't see any "alter table" request to add the "frontend_title" field in civicrm_uf_group table in the 4.7.31.mysql.tpl nor 4.7.32.mysql.tpl files ... managed somewhere else maybe, or forgotten...

Comment: Fix the issues of icons not loading and ajax search not working / ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_group` ADD  `frontend_title` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Profile Form Public title';

ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_group` ADD  `add_cancel_button` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Should a Cancel button be included in this Profile form.';

Answer (score 2):

I can see the problem (I saw this myself recently), but I don't have a 100% answer.  **However, the solution is usually to rebuild your multilingual schema.**

This problem is characterized by:

- Multilingual mode is activated on your CiviCRM site.
- Error in the browser console show files not found at a path with the word "undefined" in it.
- Also, "DB Error: no such field" errors (though this can also be caused by missing extensions or failing to upgrade the database after upgrading the CiviCRM files).

Based on [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/mlutfy/647e6325a09079e4f08f273af64900d9), here's how you rebuild the multilingual schema:

#### From within CiviCRM (CiviCRM 5.1+ only):

- Go to **Support menu » Developer » API Explorer**.
- Set *Entity* to **System** and *Action* to **rebuildmultilingualschema**.
- Press the **Execute** button.

#### From the command line (Civi 5.0.1 and earlier):

**Drupal 7**

`drush php-eval 'civicrm_initialize(); CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(["en_US","fr_CA"], NULL);'`

**Drupal 8**

`drush php-eval '\Drupal::service('civicrm')->initialize(); CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(["en_US","fr_CA"], NULL);'`

**WordPress**

`wp eval 'civicrm_initialize(); CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(["en_US","fr_CA"], NULL);'`

Comment: Hello, thanks for yr reply. I've checked the page linked to admin.php?page=Civic and here are the details : https://we.tl/Qhz1gPvzXv - I don't know where to check in this page. I've disabled all WP plugin one by one, and change the template, the error is still there. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is this a multilingual site? There have been some issues on chat about needing to rebuild the schema after upgrade - those DB errors look suspicious

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11967

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We use civicrm in French only, I've kept the en-GB and fr-fr language from the l10n package. Any other idea ?

Comment: I've seen something similar.  Can you load the "System Status" page or does it never load the dynamic (Angular) portion?  Do your Administration menu items have broken link pictures?  I had to disable logging, disable Multilingual, enable logging, disable logging, re-enable Multilingual, re-enable logging.  I'm not sure what information you will loose when you disable Multilingual, but there is a warning.

Comment: Hello Jon, yes system status is broken, broken links pictures in menu. I cannot open the 2nd page of the configuration checklist 'Address and localization of the contact" -> "CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such field" (see details here: https://we.tl/TANn6ZbCYk") Logging was not enable, neither multilanguage (only use French) / do you think a further update of civicrm will fix the issue ? this is very impacting : cannot create user, event... all pages with ajax are fully or partialy broken. Thanks

Comment: This "undefinedpackages" seems strange : as if a path variable wasn't properly defined causing the GET to fail : GET https://mysite.org/wp-admin/undefinedpackages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The DB error is a strong indicator, but you need to find the full error message. It should be in the log files found under the "ConfigAndLog" directory.

Comment: Hello @bgm - I've updated to 5.0.1 run SQL update, everything went well but still have same issues. Therefore I collected the log from "ConfigAndLog" and here are the latest record : https://we.tl/bCoR0FGqJs - an error is coming back since I've the issue : [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list']. I've checked the civicrm_uf_group table and indeed didn't find it, is there a way to correct that ? Any help will appreciated, we really stuck here. Thanks

Comment: Hello anyone could help. We've been blocked for 2 weeks now, this really impacting. Thanks

Comment: @ITSupportERELOS Did you rebuild multilingual schema as was suggested?  I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately my technical level is not sufficient to do it using apis. Any SQL request that I could use to rebuild the table ? Thanks

Comment: @ITSupportERELOS The SQL would be far too complicated.  Are you able to use the command line option above?